# Access Denied in UI to PY conversion

Tags: python, qt-designer

This is my first time using qt designer. I tried every method that I could find on the internet to convert my.Ui file to .py file. [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/01S7b.png). I even tried to use pycharm method (external tool method) yet for that method, I need pyuic5.exe which I can not find on my PC. Is there any way I can solve this problem?

Comment: Why do you have `<`s in those two pathnames?  I assume those are supposed to be backslashes.

Comment: I finally found the answer. It seems that I had 2 pythons installed python36-32 and python38-32 that is why I couldn't see the pyuic5.exe file. I deleted and started from scratch and that's when I found that problem. thank you for your help man